# How to locate httpdocs folder on Mac?

Tags: macos, apache

How to find the httpdocs folder on Mac?

This is kinda frustrating, I know **I have Apache installed** but I don't know where is that folder, after all I need to put files in there.

How I know I have Apache installed? When I type at address bar "http://localhost" I can see a page with "It Works!".

As you can see on the picture I don't have it under **Library**:
[image]

My Mac is **OS X Yosemite 10.10.13**

How do I locate that folder?
Actually I would like to define **another** folder for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find out what your apache document root is with this command:

```
$ httpd -S | grep DocumentRoot
Main DocumentRoot: "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
```

In this case it is `/Library/WebServer/Documents` folder.

You may change it editing server's config file. On Yosemite it is `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file:

```
$ httpd -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

You will need `root` password to write to this file.

Answer (score 1):

Yosemite's Apache webserver default document dir is here:
/Library/WebServer/Documents

Comment: Indeed, there is a Documents directory there with a file "index.html.en" but I cant make any change in that file to check if it is the one loaded on the page.

Comment: I just changed that file and loaded the page again, it is not it, it might be somewhere else.